# How can I *unlock* a CoreStorage volume that is not recognized?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, mount, repair, core-storage

I have a 4TB Seagate Expansion Portable Drive with <1 TB data. It's HFS+, GUID Partition, encrypted with File Vault.

It was unplugged without disconnecting, and now the disk image does not mount. It appears in disk utility as so:

[image: Disk Utility]

Running First Aid, we receive the following message:

[image: First Aid Details]

We reboot in recovery mode, and run first aid again. It provides the same dialogue.

[image: First Aid Details]

Here's the info from running diskutil info in terminal:

```
------------------
zachkrahmer$ diskutil info disk2    
   Device Identifier:        disk2    
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2    
   Whole:                    Yes    
   Part of Whole:            disk2    
   Device / Media Name:      Expansion    
   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)    
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)    
   File System:              None    
   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme    
   OS Can Be Installed:      No    
   Media Type:               Generic    
   Protocol:                 USB    
   SMART Status:             Not Supported    
   Disk Size:                4.0 TB (4000787029504 Bytes) (exactly 7814037167 512-Byte-Units)    
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes    
   Read-Only Media:          No    
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)    
   Device Location:          External    
   Removable Media:          Fixed    
   Virtual:                  No
```

Running the CS decryption command does not work, because the drive is not recognized as a CoreStorage Volume.

`zachkrahmer$ diskutil cs list

No CoreStorage logical volume groups found`

---

I tried mounting the drive, hoping that would prompt a log in request, and it only mounted a smaller (several hundred MB) EFI image.

It seems like the drive can't mount because it's locked, and it can't be unlocked because it can't mount.

It seems strange that unplugging a drive would cause "sudden death"like this.. Yes, I know it's a bad situation, and I've learned my lesson.

I'm asking for constructive advice. What else can I try, and if I reach the end of my options, could you recommend a data recovery center that specializes in corruption within FileVault encrypted drives? Many thanks.